# Display to the image view on list view click

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

I am making this news application in which I m finding difficulties. here I am using list view.here I am performing background task also and even in this I am able to fetch all the news. The only thing which is not working is when I click on list item its respective image is not showing.

How can I take the image from url and when clicked on the item, the image of that respective list is opened?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
    ListView aboutNews;
    Bitmap myImage;
    ImageView newnewImage;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> newscontent , urlImageContent;
    String finalUrl;
 
    public  void DisplayNews(String title, String urlToImage) {
             myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newscontent);   //i will not put this on oncreate because it will slow down my app.
             aboutNews.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
              newscontent.add(title);
            urlImageContent.add(urlToImage);
    }
 
        public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String result = "";
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    int data = reader.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        char current = (char) data;
                        result += current;
                        data = reader.read();
                    }
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
 
            }
 
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    String news = jsonObject.getString("articles");
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(news);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = jsonPart.getString("title");
                        String description = jsonPart.getString("description");
                        String urlToImage = jsonPart.getString("urlToImage");
                        String publish = jsonPart.getString("publishedAt");
                        String content = jsonPart.getString("content");
                        DisplayNews(title , urlToImage);
 
 
                    }
 
 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
 
                }
 
 
            }
 
 
        }
        public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
 
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {   //we have renamed strings to url
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); //it adds everything to the bitmap.
                    return myBitmap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
 
 
            }
 
        }
 
 
 
 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            newscontent = new ArrayList<String>();
           urlImageContent = new ArrayList<String>();
            aboutNews = findViewById(R.id.aboutNews);
 
 
 
 
 
 
            //.........................................................................
 
            aboutNews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
 
                        finalUrl = urlImageContent.get(i);
                        ImageDownloader task1 = new ImageDownloader();
                        try {
                            myImage = task1.execute(finalUrl).get();
                            newnewImage.setImageBitmap(myImage);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            });
            //.........................................................................
 
            downloadTask task = new downloadTask();
            try {
                task.execute("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=API_KEY");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
        }
 
 
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using something like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the images? Any specific reason?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.